# Simplifying given boolean expression

Tags: boolean, logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, digital

I've been trying to simplify this boolean expression

'((B'+C(A+D))(A'+B(C+D))(D'+B))

(the first negation is over the whole expression)

I'm getting BC'+A'D'B+AB'+AC'D'+DB' but the answer does not have the term AC'D'. Is there a way I can remove this term using absorption law or something ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both expressions are equivalent.

Expression 1 : `B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D`

Expression 2 : `B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D + A&!C&!D`

`A&!C&!D` is true when and only when A=1, C=0 and D=0

If we inject these conditions in expression 1, we have

`B&1 + 1&!B + 0&B&1 + !B&0 = B+!B =1` for all `B`

Hence when `A&!C&!D=1` the rest of the expression is also asserted and `A&!C&!D`
is redundant and can be suppressed.

It can be also proofed by algebraic methods, but is is longer.

We use the consensus theorem that states that `x&y+!x&z=x&y+!x&z+y&z`

Applying the theorem on expression 1 we get

```
B&!C + A&!B == B&!C + A&!B + A&!C
            == B&!C + A&!B + A&!C&D + A&!C&!D
```

```
B&!C + !B&D == B&!C + !B&D + !C&D
```

If we inject these redundant extra terms in expression 1 (between parenthesis for readbility)

```
(B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D) + A&!C&D + A&!C&!D + !C&D
   = (B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D) + A&!C&!D + (A&!C&D + !C&D)
   = (B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D) + A&!C&!D + !C&D
```

But as `B&!C + !B&D  + !C&D = B&!C + !B&D` thanks to the consensus theorem

We can suppress `!C&D` and we find that

```
B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D = B&!C + A&!B + !A&B&!D + !B&D + A&!C&!D
```

qed

Answer (score 0):

For such questions, [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) come in handy:

[image]

By visual inspection, it becomes clear that `AB'C'` is fully covered by `AB'`.

A nice online map generator is provided by the [University of Marburg](http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/ti1/code/karnaughmap/) (Prof. Dr. Thorsten Thormählen).